# How to determine the velocity of an object by the graph of its force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The multiple choice question reads:

> A 6-kg object is at rest on a frictionless horizontal plane.
>
> [image: Image of graph of moving object with an initial force of 0N, a constant 8N from t=1 to t=4 second, then a force of 0N at t=5 second]
>
> If the object is moved from rest by the force shown, what is the velocity of the object at time t = 4?
>
> (A) 2 m/s
>
> (B) 6 m/s
>
> (C) 12 m/s
>
> (D) 16 m/s
>
> (E) 32 m/s

My assumption to solve this is to integrate to determine the area under the curve, then divide by the mass of the object, which would result in a value of 4.67 m/s. The alleged value is 6 m/s, or choice B. Is my approach correct or am I missing a crucial component?

Comment: What do they mean by “at time  images “?

Comment: The calculation has some sort of error though its coming outnto be 5.34 m/s. The method seems correct

Comment: Yes the answer comes out to be 5.34 m/s

Comment: @Ertxiem My apologies to all for not putting the time. Updated now. Shouldn't the area of the center be 8 x (4 - 1) = 24?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the correct area, as you pointed out is $8 \times 1/2 + 8 \times (4-1) = 28$, which will result in a final velocity of $28 / 6 = 4.667 m/s$. I'll delete my wrong comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: You can get B by making a simple mistake. 8 x 1/2 + 8 x (4 - 0). Perhaps that explains the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F = ma \implies a = {F \over m}$$

As $F$ is changing with time $t$, $a$ is changing with time $t$, too:

$$a(t) = {F(t) \over m}$$

The speed $v$ is an integral of the acceleration:

$$v(4) = \int_0^4 a(t)\, \mathrm dt = \int_0^4 {F(t) \over m}\, \mathrm dt = \frac 1 m\int_0^4 {F(t)}\, \mathrm dt\tag1\label 1$$

$\int_0^4 {F(t)}\, \mathrm dt$ is the area under your graph, i. e. the area of the  firs triangle and one rectangle, so

$$\int_0^4 {F(t)}\, \mathrm dt = {1 \cdot 8 \over 2}+ 3\cdot 8 = 28$$

Substituting it and the mass into $\eqref 1$ you will obtain

$$v(4) = \frac 1 6\cdot 28 = 4\cfrac {_{2}} {^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as this is the net force as a function of time, the area would be the impulse (change in momentum). You can find the object’s change if velocity. It’s not clear what “time images” mean as pointed out. The approach is fine but question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same answer as you: $4/6+3\cdot8/6=4.667 $
I think I'd be questioning that question.

Comment: That 's the same methods used to calculate voltage on a capacitor, or current through an inductor. Mine for a constant current, or  voltage. Yours for a current or voltage function.

Answer (score -1):

At the instant $t=4$, force $F = 8N$

As
$$F = \frac{dp}{dt}$$
$$p = \int{Fdt} = \int{8dt} = 8t$$
Now, $p = mv$

$$v = {p \over m} = \frac{8t}{6}$$
At t = 4 s,

$$v = \frac{8\cdot4}{6} = 5.333\; \mathrm {ms^{-1}} $$